# MYSQL GROUP BY WITH COUNT

Tags: mysql

I'm breaking my fingers on my head to solve a `query` that must result on agroupments of `count days` ON each `place id` *and the* `where clause` is an `id from another table`. 
So, i have `place(Foreign Key FROM places)`, day and `pk(Foreign Key from another table)`.
I want to count how many times the `place X` appears ON query table with `pk = y` ?

the table to fetch the data ():

```
pk  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
pi  int(11) NO  MUL     
anuncio int(11) NO  MUL     
local   int(11) NO  MUL
insercoes   int(11) YES         
dia datetime    YES         
dataUi  datetime    YES 
valorTabela varchar(45) YES         
sts tinyint(4)  YES     1
```

the query that i tried to make:

```
SELECT 
pa.local AS local,
COUNT(pa.local),
lo.valorTabela AS valorTabela
FROM pi_anuncios pa
INNER JOIN locais lo ON(pa.local = lo.id)
WHERE  pa.pi = 155 GROUP BY pa.local;
```

Comment: Can you post your query and your table structure. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: pk int(11) NO PRI  auto_increment
pi int(11) NO MUL  
anuncio int(11) NO MUL  
local int(11) NO MUL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page has a great example of what you're trying to do:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php

Just modify the Count(*) to count the PK column from the other table in your join.

Here is the SQL command from the linked article:

```
SELECT country,COUNT(*) 
FROM author 
GROUP BY country;
```

Comment: Great and Simple! thks a lot @Askanison4!

Comment: You should probably add the specific part of the article that you think solves OP's problem in the answer itself, to keep the answer valid even if the link goes away.

Comment: @FilipeSilva Done. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

I understood:

You need to count the number of times X appeared on a table having it's pk value equal to y and this pk comes from other table. Here I have given it in WHERE  condition.

Please let me know for any further help.

```
SELECT PLACE, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE PK IN (SELECT ID FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE ID = 'Y')
GROUP BY PLACE
```

Comment: Nope, its not equal to y but equal to place(fk)